# Google maps as a background of the widget in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to implement a google maps as a background of my widget. I have two divs, one for map, and another one for the text which should be on top of the map. To achieve that I use different values of the z-index in the css file. Here is the code of the widget:

```
echo $before_widget;
  $bg_image_style = '';
  if ( !empty( $background_image ) ) {
     $bg_image_style .= 'background-image:url(' . $background_image . ');background-attachment:' . $bg_attachment . ';background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:cover;';
  }else {?>
  <?php }?>
  <?php if ( !empty( $background_image ) ) {?>
       <div class="call-to-action-content-wrapper clearfix"  style="<?php echo $bg_image_style; ?>">
  <?php } else {?>
       <div id="container">
  <?php }?>
     <div class="inner-wrap">
        <?php if( !empty( $text_main ) ) { ?>
           <h3>
              <?php echo esc_html( $text_main );
              if( !empty( $button_text ) ) { ?>
                 <a class="call-to-action-button" href="<?php echo $button_url; ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( $button_text ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( $button_text ); ?></a>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php if( empty( $button_text ) ) { ?>
                  <a class="fancybox-inline call-to-action-button" href="#contact_form_pop">Contact us</a>
              <?php } ?>
           </h3>
        <?php } ?>
     </div>
  <div id='map-canvas'></div>
  </div>

  <?php echo $after_widget;
```

If the background image $background_image is not empty, I use:

```
<div class="call-to-action-content-wrapper clearfix"  style="<?php echo $bg_image_style; ?>">
```

However, when its empty, I want to have a map in the background, so I use another div:

```
<div id="container">
```

And after the ending tag of the "container" div I put a map div:

```
 <div id='map-canvas'></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .business-template .widget.widget_call_to_action_block .call-to-action-    content-wrapper {
      padding: 100px 0;
    }

    .call-to-action-content-wrapper h3 {
    padding-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 26px;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    }

    #map-canvas {
    height: 500px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    }

    #container {
    z-index: 100;
    position: relative;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    height: 0;
    }
    .clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
    }

   .inner-wrap {
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 9999;
    }

   .business-template .widget.widget_call_to_action_block > .inner-wrap,
   .business-template .widget.widget_portfolio_block > .inner-wrap {
    max-width: 100%;
    }
```

However, the map is always on top, despite the z-index. Do you have any suggestions in the html and css? Maybe I do something wrong.

Comment: Do you mind providing a live link?

Comment: The website is still on the local machine. If you need any further code, I can paste it here.

Comment: I guess there is a problem with positioning. When I use position:absolute to the map-canvas and the position:relative to the container, the map appears underneath the text. However, I have to put some weird numbers like top:3668px to the map div to see it on the bottom of the site. Otherwise its in the top corner of the website.

Comment: My question now would be is it possible to perform a stack ordering of two div's which one of them doesnt have a position and z-index? In example I have map canvas without z-index and position, and container with position: relative and z-index. Is that possible in this way to display a container on top of map?

Comment: Of course, since the container has the z-index value you can set it to whatever you like... e.g. set it to 100 and you should see the container above the map canvas. You can use jsfiddle to reproduce the problem so I can help you.